# Extract text between brackets using google spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula

I want to extract the text between brackets in a cell (X3), but the usual excel formulas give a parse error in google spreadsheets.

For example:

```
=MID(X3,FIND("[",X3)+1,FIND("]",X3)-FIND("[",X3)-1)
```

How to fix this parse error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

You have regular brackets so use:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(X3,"\((.*)\)")
```

Or change your formula to

```
=MID(X3,FIND("(",X3)+1,FIND(")",X3)-FIND("(",X3)-1)
```

If you have both `()` and `[]` in your data you can use:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(X3,"[\[\(](.*)[\)\]]")
```

Comment: It still doesn't work (parse error) A screenshot of my spreadsheet on the link below:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1fiv0AmtbFBQTVKYVF6LThfaGM

Comment: @cwille That is a link for locked drive document.

Comment: @cwille Both formulas work, the problem might be in `X3`

Comment: sorry, this is the public link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1fiv0AmtbFBQTVKYVF6LThfaGM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your brackets aren't `[]` they are `()`

Comment: @zipa Super weak at Regex, if I wanted just `[]`, what would the regex be?